# .net threading: passing custom class ref as a parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am new to Threading in .net and I am maintaining an application written in MVC 5.
The application has a static Utility class which has a static PostRequests method to process Web Client requests. 
From the webpage, I start 3 threads which will call this static method to get data from 3 different sources.

Each Webclient request has a timeout of 45 sec. But one of the thread prints log of around 30sec only and dies without completing the job.
I read few articles where it's written that reference variable need to be made thread safe and I am not sure how to do it.
My question is: 
Is the method Thread Safe? Am I making a mistake somewhere in parameters or accessing variables?

Here is the method

```
private static Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

public static List<T> PostRequests<T>(string url, string querystring, Request request) where T : IResponse
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(querystring))
                querystring = "?apikey=" + AppSettings.APIAccessKey;
            else
                querystring = querystring + "&apikey=" + AppSettings.APIAccessKey;
            var timestamp = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", DateTime.UtcNow);

            WsfWebClient client = new WsfWebClient();

            var headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
            headers.Add("timestamp", timestamp);
            headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

            var message = Signer.BuildMessage(url, "POST", HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring), timestamp);
            var signature = Signer.ComputeHash(AppSettings.APISecretKey, message);

            headers.Add("signature", signature);

            client.Headers = headers;                

            var json = request.ToJsonString();

            Logger.Debug(String.Format("SDK: Posting data to the API. JSON: {0}", json));

            timer.Start();
            var response = client.UploadData(AppSettings.APIUrl + url + querystring, "POST", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json));
            timer.Stop();
            Logger.Info(string.Format("Time Spent for : WSF Call  - {0}", timer.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString()));

            return ParseListResponse<T>(Encoding.Default.GetString(response));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("SDK: Post Request to Builder API failed.", ex, typeof(Utilities));
            var responseObject = GetInstance<List<T>>();

            if (responseObject.Count > 0)
            {
                responseObject[0].GenerateError("", "Post Request to Builder API failed.", ex.StackTrace);
            }

            return responseObject;
        }
    }


public class WsfWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        // Set timeout for 45 seconds
        request.Timeout = AppSettings.WsfWebClientTimeOut; 
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. There's an awful lot in here which has nothing to do with your question, and it makes it harder to find the relevant information.

Comment: (I suspect the problem may well be that you're making too many requests to the same host, and that they're blocking each other. It doesn't help that you're not disposing of the response, which means it will block the connection pool until it's garbage collected. Finally, using `Encoding.Default` is almost certainly the wrong approach here. Use the encoding you expect the response to be in.

Comment: I am making only 3 calls to the Web Service will that have too much impact?

Comment: It will if the connection limit is 2, yes... I can't remember what the default is. (I thought it was 4, but maybe not.) And if you don't dispose of the responses, then you're at the mercy of garbage collection so the *next* round of requests will still be blocked by *this* round of requests. So the *first* thing to do is put a `using` statement on your `UploadData` call.

Comment: and won't  WebClient request create a new worker process if it's getting blocked (Sorry I have limited knowledge on this, I am just clarifying)

Comment: Ahhh.. got your point

Comment: It doesn't create any processes at all... but the point is that it uses a pool of connections, so that it doesn't need to keep reopening them. I don't have time to elucidate further right now, unfortunately.